# Printing in a row of other table once a row is selected from other table of same jframe

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to print a text in a row of a JTable once clicked on a row of another JTable in the same JFrame.

To be precise my table1 contains two columns and table 2 contains 4 columns. When a user has clicked on a row1  from table 2 the message which will be mentioned should print in table 1 .for example column 1 "hi" column2 "welcome"

Comment: `ActionListener`/`MouseListener` will do what you want

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: Your title says "once a row is selected". Then you say "once clicked on a row". Well a row can be selected by using the keyboard up/down arrow keys. So what is your real requirement. Usually you don't do process on a selection buy either when you double click on the row or use the Enter key. Another option is to add a button to click on. This way you can select multiple rows at a time and then process them all when the button is clicked.

Comment: So what exactly is your requirement and what is your problem.? Do you know how to use a MouseListener? Do you know how to use "Key Bindings" to do something when a KeyStroke is pressed? Do you know how to get the data from the selected table? Do you know how to add data to another table?

Comment: actually I am new to java swing.  I will explain the requirement again,  there are two tables in two different panels but in same jframe .there is data in a rows of table 2 and no data in rows of table 1 .when any row in table 2 is selected the hardcoded message should be displayed in table 1.for example if row1 from tabel2 selected data in row 1 table 1 displayed . But table 2 have four coulmns and table one have 2 columns. Just to make sure when row1 from table 2 selected should not display same data in row 1 of table1.

Comment: actually I am new to java swing.  I will explain the requirement again,  there are two tables in two different panels but in same jframe .there is data in a rows of table 2 and no data in rows of table 1 .when any row in table 2 is selected the hardcoded message should be displayed in table 1.for example if row1 from tabel2 selected data in row 1 table 1 displayed . But table 2 have four coulmns and table one have 2 columns. Just to make sure when row1 from table 2 selected should not display same data in row 1 of table1.